# Extension for required reading time

Tags: web-browser, firefox, reading

Is there any extension that can tell me how much time it would take a person to read a page?

I need for Firefox.

Comment: What do you mean by "how much"?  Do you mean time?

Comment: yes, I mean time

Comment: If you have the latest version of Firefox, doesn't it come with it already? You just activate Reader Mode and it should work, at least that's what I thought. But maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I have a reader icon at the end of the URL bar (Enter Reader View). But doesn't show how much would it take to read the page. Where shall I look?

Comment: What do you mean by "read a page"? The page loading time? How long it will take **you** to read the page? Your question at the moment is unclear.

Comment: The necessary time for me to read the page, not the loading time.

Comment: I guess you mean an estimate for the read duration, as, e.g., used by [Medium](https://medium.com/), right?

Comment: yes, I need an estimate